# Should the Controller interact directly with the auto-generated Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a project using MVC and Entity Framework. For now, what I am doing is that I am using the Controllers to directly do "TryUpdateModel" within their Action methods using the auto-generated Model by the Entity Framework.

My question would be, is this a good / recommended approach? Of course, the Model I am passing still to a repository class for further processing and saving.

I am curious. What if I create a "wrapper" model to the auto-generated one? Can the ViewModel be this "wrapper" model?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Noted! Will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts are good. It's better to use the *wrapper model* instead of the autogenerated one. Because autogenerated model have the role of DAO (Data Access Object) and sometimes don't fit with your needs for View Model.

The actual View Model should be the *wrapper model*. Because sometimes you only want a *chunk* of your DAOs (*autogenerated model*).

Comment: And sometimes you want a combination of chunks of different DAOs.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid directly updating the model or make sure you explicitly set which properties it's allowed to bind to. The reason is that the method you are using is opening up your code to vulnerability called overposting.

Overposting in short is that a hacker modifies the form to inject properties they are not supposed to be able to update. See here: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Other than that it's a design desicion like any other. Both ways have some pros and cons. You get less code to write/maintain if you do it your way. But once you need to make changes you have less flexibility because the form and the model need to match, which is not always the best way to build the form.